# Best way to boost the performance of my LWJGL game?

Tags: java, render, lwjgl, frame-rate, lag

I am putting together a small project for school that involves rendering the periodic table.  I chose to use LWJGL to do this.  The problem is, however, that when I render the table, the game starts out at ~30fps(capped at 60fps), and quickly fluctuates to a single-digit fps.  I believe that the problem could be a memory leak, but I am unsure.  Can anybody see any glaring problems with my code?  Here are the main classes involved in rendering the table:

EntityPeriodicTable: In charge of holding a huge array of EntityElement objects(see below), activating their logic(tick() and updateInput()).
    package com.flafla2.periodicTable;

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class EntityPeriodicTable extends ClickableEntity { //ClickableEntity is an abstract class in charge of the tick(), updateInput(), and render() methods, as well as positioning

    public EntityElement[] elements = {//This is unfinished, but you get the idea.
        //new EntityElement(Atomic #, State, Metal, "Symbol", "Name", new Vector2D(posx,posy), this)
        new EntityElement(1, 2, 2, "H", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(1,1), this),
        new EntityElement(2, 2, 2, "He", "Helium", new Vector2D(18,1), this),

        new EntityElement(3, 0, 0, "Li", "Lithium", new Vector2D(1,2), this),
        new EntityElement(4, 0, 0, "Be", "Beryllium", new Vector2D(2,2), this),
        new EntityElement(5, 0, 1, "B", "Boron", new Vector2D(13,2), this),
        new EntityElement(6, 0, 2, "C", "Carbon", new Vector2D(14,2), this),
        new EntityElement(7, 2, 2, "N", "Nitrogen", new Vector2D(15,2), this),
        new EntityElement(8, 2, 2, "O", "Oxygen", new Vector2D(16,2), this),
        new EntityElement(9, 2, 2, "F", "Fluorine", new Vector2D(17,2), this),
        new EntityElement(10,2, 2, "Ne", "Neon", new Vector2D(18,2), this),

        new EntityElement(11, 0, 0, "Na", "Sodium", new Vector2D(1,3), this),
        new EntityElement(12, 0, 0, "Mg", "Magnesium", new Vector2D(2,3), this),
        new EntityElement(13, 0, 0, "Al", "Aluminum", new Vector2D(13,3), this),
        new EntityElement(14, 0, 1, "Si", "Silicon", new Vector2D(14,3), this),
        new EntityElement(15, 0, 2, "P", "Phosphorous", new Vector2D(15,3), this),
        new EntityElement(16, 0, 2, "S", "Sulfur", new Vector2D(16,3), this),
        new EntityElement(17, 2, 2, "Cl", "Chlorine", new Vector2D(17,3), this),
        new EntityElement(18, 2, 2, "Ar", "Argon", new Vector2D(18,3), this),

        new EntityElement(19, 0, 0, "K", "Potassium", new Vector2D(1,4), this),
        new EntityElement(20, 0, 0, "Ca", "Calcium", new Vector2D(2,4), this),
        new EntityElement(21, 0, 0, "Sc", "Scandium", new Vector2D(3,4), this),
        new EntityElement(22, 0, 0, "Ti", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(4,4), this),
        new EntityElement(23, 0, 0, "V", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(5,4), this),
        new EntityElement(24, 0, 0, "Cr", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(6,4), this),
        new EntityElement(25, 0, 0, "Mn", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(7,4), this),
        new EntityElement(26, 0, 0, "Fe", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(8,4), this),
        new EntityElement(27, 0, 0, "Co", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(9,4), this),
        new EntityElement(28, 0, 0, "Ni", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(10,4), this),
        new EntityElement(29, 0, 0, "Cu", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(11,4), this),
        new EntityElement(30, 0, 0, "Zn", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(12,4), this),
        new EntityElement(31, 0, 0, "Ga", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(13,4), this),
        new EntityElement(32, 0, 1, "Ge", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(14,4), this),
        new EntityElement(33, 0, 1, "As", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(15,4), this),
        new EntityElement(34, 0, 2, "Se", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(16,4), this),
        new EntityElement(35, 1, 2, "Br", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(17,4), this),
        new EntityElement(36, 2, 2, "Kr", "Hydrogen", new Vector2D(18,4), this),
    };

    public final int ELEMENT_SIZE = 40;
    public Vector2D mousePos = new Vector2D(0,0); //Simple 2D vector struct.

    public double[] SOLID_RGB = {0,0,0};
    public double[] LIQUID_RGB = {0,0,1};
    public double[] GAS_RGB = {1,0,0};

    public double[] METAL_RGB;
    public double[] NONMETAL_RGB;
    public double[] METALLOID_RGB;
    public double[] RECENT_RGB;

    public EntityPeriodicTable(Vector2D pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
        METAL_RGB = new double[3];
        METAL_RGB[0] = 0.596078431; //152/255
        METAL_RGB[1] = 0.984313725; //251/255
        METAL_RGB[2] = 0.596078431; //152/255

        NONMETAL_RGB = new double[3];
        NONMETAL_RGB[0] = 1;
        NONMETAL_RGB[1] = 0.647058824; //165/255
        NONMETAL_RGB[2] = 0;

        METALLOID_RGB = new double[3];
        METALLOID_RGB[0] = 0.866666667; //221/255
        METALLOID_RGB[1] = 0.62745098; //160/255
        METALLOID_RGB[2] = 0.866666667; //221/255

        RECENT_RGB = new double[3];
        RECENT_RGB[0] = 0.803921569; //205/255
        RECENT_RGB[1] = 0.788235294; //201/255
        RECENT_RGB[2] = 0.788235294; //201/255
    }

    @Override
    void render() {
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        for(int x=0;x<elements.length;x++)
            elements[x].render();
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        for(int x=0;x<elements.length;x++)
            elements[x].renderWithTex();
    }

    @Override
    void tick() {
        for(int x=0;x<elements.length;x++)
            elements[x].tick();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateInput(Vector2D mousePos)
    {
        this.mousePos = mousePos;
        for(int x=0;x<elements.length;x++)
        {
            if(mousePos.isInBoundsWithDim(elements[x].pos.x, elements[x].pos.y, elements[x].dim.x, elements[x].dim.y))
                elements[x].isSelected = true;
            else
                elements[x].isSelected = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    void onEntityClicked() {
        for(int x=0;x<elements.length;x++)
        {
            if(mousePos.isInBoundsWithDim(elements[x].pos.x, elements[x].pos.y, elements[x].dim.x, elements[x].dim.y))
                elements[x].onEntityClicked();
        }
    }

}
```

EntityElement: Holds data of a specific element on the table, and renders it(render code is unfinished)

```
package com.flafla2.periodicTable;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class EntityElement extends ClickableEntity {

    String symbol;
    String element;
    int atomicNumber;
    EntityPeriodicTable table;
    int state;//0=solid, 1=liquid, 2=gas
    int metalState;//0=metal, 1=metalloid, 2=nonmetal, 3=discovered recently
    Vector2D gridPos;

    public EntityElement(int an, int st, int ms, String sy, String en, Vector2D gp, EntityPeriodicTable pt)
    {
        symbol = sy;
        element = en;
        atomicNumber = an;
        table = pt;
        state = st;
        metalState = ms;
        gridPos = gp;

        dim.x = table.ELEMENT_SIZE; dim.y = table.ELEMENT_SIZE;
        pos.x = table.pos.x + table.ELEMENT_SIZE*(gridPos.x-1); pos.y = table.pos.y + table.ELEMENT_SIZE*(gridPos.y-1);
    }

    public double[] getStateColor()
    {
        switch(state)
        {
        case 0:
            return table.SOLID_RGB;
        case 1:
            return table.LIQUID_RGB;
        case 2:
            return table.GAS_RGB;
        default:
            double[] d = {0.0d,0.0d,0.0d};
            return d;
        }
    }

    public double[] getMetalColor()
    {
        switch(metalState)
        {
        case 0:
            return table.METAL_RGB;
        case 1:
            return table.METALLOID_RGB;
        case 2:
            return table.NONMETAL_RGB;
        case 3:
            return table.RECENT_RGB;
        default:
            double[] d = {0.0d,0.0d,0.0d};
            return d;
        }
    }

    @Override
    void render() {
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glTranslatef(pos.x, pos.y, 0);
            double[] d = getMetalColor();
            GL11.glColor3d(d[0], d[1], d[2]);
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            {
                GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);//topleft
                GL11.glVertex2f(dim.x, 0);//topright
                GL11.glVertex2f(dim.x, dim.y);//bottomright
                GL11.glVertex2f(0, dim.y);//bottomleft
            }
            GL11.glEnd();
            GL11.glColor3d(1.0d, 1.0d, 1.0d);
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }

    public void renderWithTex()
    {
        Font.drawString(symbol, new Vector2D(pos.x+dim.x/2-Font.getStringWidth(symbol,2)/2,pos.y+dim.y/2-Font.FONT_HEIGHT), 2);
    }

    @Override
    void tick() {
        if(isSelected)
        {
            dim.x = table.ELEMENT_SIZE+6; dim.y = table.ELEMENT_SIZE+6;
            pos.x = table.pos.x + table.ELEMENT_SIZE*(gridPos.x-1)-3; pos.y = table.pos.y + table.ELEMENT_SIZE*(gridPos.y-1)-3;
        } else
        {
            dim.x = table.ELEMENT_SIZE; dim.y = table.ELEMENT_SIZE;
            pos.x = table.pos.x + table.ELEMENT_SIZE*(gridPos.x-1); pos.y = table.pos.y + table.ELEMENT_SIZE*(gridPos.y-1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    void onEntityClicked() {

    }

}
```

Font: Handles rendering text onscreen:

```
package com.flafla2.periodicTable;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Font {
    public static final String fontText = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789:;?!\"&',-.[]#()+ ";
    public static final BufferedImage fontSheet = TextureLoader.loadTexture("/res/text.png");

    public static final int FONT_WIDTH = 9;
    public static final int FONT_HEIGHT = 8;

    public static void drawString(String s, Vector2D pos, float dim)
    {
        drawString(s,pos,new Vector2D((int)Math.floor(dim*FONT_WIDTH),(int)Math.floor(dim*FONT_HEIGHT)));
    }

    public static void drawString(String s, Vector2D pos)
    {
        drawString(s,pos,new Vector2D(9,8));
    }

    public static void drawString(String s, Vector2D pos, Vector2D dim)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<s.length();x++)
        {
            drawLetter(s.charAt(x),new Vector2D(pos.x+dim.x*x,pos.y),dim);
        }
    }

    public static int getStringWidth(String s)
    {
        return s.length()*FONT_WIDTH;
    }

    public static int getStringWidth(String s,float f)
    {
        return (int)Math.floor(s.length()*FONT_WIDTH*f);
    }

    public static Vector2D getPosOfLetterOnImg(Character c,int gridNumb)
    {
        int xOffset = 0;
        int yOffset = 0;
        if(!c.equals(' '))
        {
            int letterNumb = fontText.indexOf(c);
            xOffset = (letterNumb%26)*FONT_WIDTH;
            if(xOffset != 0)
                xOffset -=1;
            yOffset = 0;
            int yGridOffset = (letterNumb < 26) ? 0 : ((letterNumb < 52) ? 1 : 2);

            switch(gridNumb)
            {
            case 1:
                yOffset = 34;
                break;
            case 2:
                yOffset = 69;
                break;
            default:
                yOffset = 0;
            }

            for(int x=0;x<yGridOffset;x++)
                yOffset += FONT_HEIGHT+x+3;
        } else
        {
            xOffset = 235;
            yOffset = 92;
        }

        return new Vector2D(xOffset,yOffset);
    }

    public static void drawLetter(Character c, Vector2D pos, Vector2D dim)
    {
        if(fontSheet == null)
            return;

        Vector2D letterPos = getPosOfLetterOnImg(c,2);

        BufferedImage letterImage = fontSheet.getSubimage(letterPos.x, letterPos.y, FONT_WIDTH, FONT_HEIGHT);
        int textureID = TextureLoader.loadGLTexture(letterImage);
        letterImage = null;

        GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glTranslatef(pos.x, pos.y, 0);
            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            {
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);

                GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                GL11.glVertex2f(dim.x, 0);

                GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                GL11.glVertex2f(dim.x, dim.y);

                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                GL11.glVertex2f(0, dim.y);
            }
            GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

TextureLoader: Loads textures(duh lol)

```
package com.flafla2.periodicTable;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12;

public class TextureLoader {
    public static BufferedImage loadTexture(String texturePath)
    {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(PeriodicTable.class.getResource(texturePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static final int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;
    public static int loadGLTexture(BufferedImage image){
         int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
         image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());

         ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * BYTES_PER_PIXEL); //4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB

         for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){
             for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
                 int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
                 buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));     // Red component
                 buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));      // Green component
                 buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));               // Blue component
                 buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));    // Alpha component. Only for RGBA
             } 
         }

         buffer.flip(); //FOR THE LOVE OF GOD DO NOT FORGET THIS

         // You now have a ByteBuffer filled with the color data of each pixel.
         // Now just create a texture ID and bind it. Then you can load it using 
         // whatever OpenGL method you want, for example:

         int textureID = GL11.glGenTextures(); //Generate texture ID
         GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); //Bind texture ID

         //Setup wrap mode
         GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
         GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

         //Setup texture scaling filtering
         GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
         GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);

         //Send texel data to OpenGL
         GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
         buffer = null;

         //Return the texture ID so we can bind it later again
         return textureID;
    }
}
```

I know, it's a lot of code, but if anyone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Flafla2.

Comment: You say memory leak, have you tried watching usage? You're `new`ing a lot of vectors, which is normal and fine, but that'd be the first place I'd look. If you can, try profiling CPU and memory use, and see where the hotspots are. Note, though, that profiling your render code *on the CPU* will provide *incorrect data and should be mostly ignored* (the driver/card buffers so heavily that a CPU profile won't match up).

Comment: Thanks, I will try profiling now(I was having trouble with the profiler before, I will see if I can fix the problem).

Comment: Alright, I found the problem.

In `TextureLoader.java`, I didn't use `glDeleteTextures(textureID)`, so the textures used in `Font.java` weren't being unloaded from memory.  Now, I am getting a stable 50+ fps(on my crappy macbook, of course).  Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Awesome. If you want, I can copy my comment to an answer (or you could answer yourself), so you can accept and close the question.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to because my low-reputation forced me to wait 8 hours before I could answer my own question.  When the time is up, though, I will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem.

In `TextureLoader.java`, I didn't use `glDeleteTextures(textureID)`, so the textures used in `Font.java` weren't being unloaded from memory.  Now, I am getting a stable 50+ fps(on my crappy macbook, of course).

Also, the other checked answer boosted my fps to ~60.  In case anyone is wondering, here is the new `drawLetter()` method, with changes:

```
public static void drawLetter(Character c, Vector2D pos, Vector2D dim)
    {
        if(fontSheet == null)
            return;

        Vector2D letterPos = getPosOfLetterOnImg(c,2);

        //BufferedImage letterImage = fontSheet.getSubimage(letterPos.x, letterPos.y, FONT_WIDTH, FONT_HEIGHT);
        //int textureID = TextureLoader.loadGLTexture(letterImage);
        //letterImage = null;

        int width = fontSheet.getWidth(); int height = fontSheet.getHeight();
        double d[] = {(double)letterPos.x/width, (double)letterPos.y/height, (double)(letterPos.x+FONT_WIDTH)/width, (double)(letterPos.y+FONT_HEIGHT)/height};
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glTranslatef(pos.x, pos.y, 0);
            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            {
                GL11.glTexCoord2d(d[0], d[1]);
                GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);

                GL11.glTexCoord2d(d[2], d[1]);
                GL11.glVertex2f(dim.x, 0);

                GL11.glTexCoord2d(d[2], d[3]);
                GL11.glVertex2f(dim.x, dim.y);

                GL11.glTexCoord2d(d[0], d[3]);
                GL11.glVertex2f(0, dim.y);
            }
            GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glPopMatrix();

        //GL11.glDeleteTextures(textureID);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought you allready solved it there is more room for improvement. I see you have your font in an image and for each character you want to draw you get the part of the image with that letter load it into a texture and afterwards all that needs to be cleaned up.

Better to load the whole image into one big texture, keep that texture for the duration of your program and reuse it when rendering each frame. You can select the right characters to render by specifying the right texture coordinates.

You should be able to hit your 60fps cap with low cpu usage unless your MacBook is really old.

Comment: Thanks, that brought my FPS from ~30 to ~60!